# Why would the upper radiator hose be hot and the lower radiator hose be cool?

Tags: radiator

I changed thermostat and heating core.  Hoses have been flushed. Truck (2010 Dodge Ram)temp gauge started running hot.  Upper radiator hose hot and lower is cool.  Is it safe to drive?

Comment: Definitely need more info here, the top hose gets hot first ie hot water rises -even without the action of the pump.

Comment: Is the upper hose hot all the way to the radiator, or just close to the engine. Is any part of the radiator hot?